# Passing a Facebook Oauth2 object while using Tornado

Tags: python, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0, tornado

I am trying to implement oauth manually on my website which is being implemented using tornado. My url (localhost/form) contains a button which when clicked brings up a facebook login and then if the login is successful redirects back to the same site with a token (localhost/form?code=XXX) where I collect the token/code and begins taking requests from facebook.

My issue is that upon redirecting back to localhost/form with a given code, it appears that I reinitialize a brand new oauth2session object which does not match up with the token and I receive a GET request error. How should I correctly pass this oauth2session object or correctly reinitialize it? Is this reinitialization causing my error or something else? My current code which does not work is:

```
class FormHandler (BaseHandler):
 def get(self):
        client_id =XXX
        client_secret =XXX
        authorization_base_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth'
        token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token'

        facebook = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri='http://localhost/form')
        facebook = facebook_compliance_fix(facebook)
        authorization_url, state = facebook.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
        self.write('<button id="FacebookManual" type="button">Facebook Manual</button><br><script> document.getElementById("FacebookManual").onclick = function () {location.href ="'+authorization_url+'";};</script>')

        #Check to see if I get redirected with a code
        authorization_code=self.get_argument("code", default=None, strip=False)
        if authorization_code is not None:
            redirect_response='https://localhost/form/?code='+authorization_code
            facebook.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret, authorization_response=redirect_response)
            r = facebook.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me?')
            self.write('Hello'+r.content)

#Roughly how my tornado is set up
def make_app():
 return Application(
   [
    url('/', BaseHandler, { "var":"nothing" }, name="root"), # this is for the root! :)
    url('/form', FormHandler, { "var":"initialize this!" }, name = "forlorn"),
   ],
# settings:
   debug = True,
```

)

Edit: A friend advised me to include the error that I was receiving. The error that I get is a oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MismatchingStateError: (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /form?code=XxX